# RxJS - Concurrent paging

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, rxjs

I'm facing a bit of a tricky problem and feel like my limited knowledge of RxJS is preventing me from reaching a solution.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is page an api endpoint in page sizes of 100, then for each page of data I receive perform an ajax request on each item. However I'm running into some performance issues when retrieving the pages of data, I assumed forkJoin would be exactly what I needed but it doesn't seem to be running the ajax requests in parellel as the operator suggests, this is leading to rather long wait times before the data is ready to process.

So my question is, how can I retrieve pages of data without having to rely on the previous page being fetched?

Comment: Could you post a **minimal** reproducible code for your issue? Because `forkJoin` should do the job if you use it correctly

Comment: Also if you want to make 100 concurrent requests they will be queued because browsers have limitations on number of connections, see - http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top

Comment: I will post an example when I get home this evening. The reason I suspect its not executing the requests in parallel is because when looking at the network log on chrome dev tools its appears as if a request only fires after the previous has returned.

Comment: So I just ran a small test as work, and it appears it is due to the browsers limitation, with around 5 requests they execute in parallel, kicking that up to say 10, 20 etc causes them to be queued :/

Comment: Less related to your question and more to concurrent requests in browsers, but [look into domain sharding](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/parallel-downloads-across-domains/).

Comment: The article looked interesting but its seems it's outdated as of HTTP/2?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this might be the github users project.

If, say, fetching avatar_url after fetching a list of users, `forkjoin` is going to wait for completion of all 100 requests until it emits anything.

`flatMap` is going to be a perceived improvement in the UI as it will emit each response as it arrives. But, does not alter the overall time to completion or the problem of browser limited connections.

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with GitHub's API. Regardless, I've found the problem lies more in the browsers capability to perform a large number of concurrent requests. Chrome is limited to 6 apparently.